# Angular 2+ Dynamically creating form inputs using template-driven forms works in production errors in unit testing

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular2-forms

I am trying to create a dynamic form that is generated and populated by previous selections by the user. Each profile selected by the user contains a Config array that is looped through to create subsequent inputs.

A Config Object looks pretty much like this:

```
 {
      Description: "A name for your security control, can have a maximum of 64 characters"
      MaxLength: 64
      Name: "Name"
      Pattern: "^(.{1,64})$"
      Type: "text"
 }
```

This all works fine during production, but when I attempt to run a unit test I get the error:

```
 Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
  control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.
```

I am setting a name dynamically, so I don't understand why this isn't working.

```
 <div class="sc-config-form__input" *ngFor="let config of profile.Config">
      <label *ngIf="!config.Conditional || isConditionMet(config)" class="cloud-grey-label fillLabel" for="sc{{config.Name}}-text">{{config.Name}}</label>
      <input *ngIf="(!config.Conditional || isConditionMet(config)) && (!config.Type || config.Type =='text')"
              maxlength="{{config.MaxLength}}"
              name="{{config.Name}}"
              [ngModel]="config.Default"
              type="text"  
              id="sc{{config.Name}}-text"
              placeholder="{{config.Name}}"
              pattern="{{(config.Pattern ? config.Pattern : '')}}"
              title="{{config.Description}}"
              [required]="config.Required"
       />
 />
```

I have also attempted to use "let i = index" and dynamically adding the index to the name attribute. This allows it to pass the test, but then the name of my control is wrong and it doesn't work in production for a myriad of reasons.

Is there an easier way to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Inside of your input tag you need to add

```
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
```

This will resolve your issue.